# SOAP header missing error - Please help!

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis, rampart

I am trying to run the example of signing and encryption described here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jws5/.
I am getting the following error when running the client, any help please!

Many thanks,

## Client log

run:
java Connecting to http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/library-signencr
java 16:32:59,188 ERROR AxisEngine:211 - SOAP header missing
java org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: SOAP header missing
java at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
java at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:99)

## Tomcat log

ERROR org/opensaml/xml/validation/ValidatingXMLObject
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opensaml/xml/validation/ValidatingXMLObject

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the following:

- To copy all jar and modules files from %RAMPART_HOME%/lib and /modules to %AXIS_HOME%/lib and /modules
- Generate the axis2.war using the build.xml file in the axis2 installation directory
- Redeploy the axis2.war into Tomcat